# Save custom flag content if dialog is dismissed

Tags: feature-request, flags, user-interface, flag-dialog

**UPDATE**

There's a [userscript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408348/13138080) over on MSO that does the job - just needs the `@match` headers - by Oleg Valter, using localStorage to save the content while still allowing the dialog to be closed by clicking outside of it.  Thanks, Oleg!

---

Some time ago, I wrote a pretty lengthy custom flag and accidentally closed the flag dialog by clicking just under the "flag" button, which deleted all the content I wrote.  This is *really* annoying.  Yes, you can nav back to the dialog and write it again, and this doesn't happen often (with me at least), but that takes time and I prefer to take action.

Can we have the text stored in a manner similar to the Q/A drafts, or localStorage (or any way really) so we don't lose our content with a simple, stupid accidental click?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate (on MSO), for reference: [Clicking outside of the flag/close dialog should not dismiss the flag dialog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408302/clicking-outside-of-the-flag-close-dialog-should-not-dismiss-the-flag-dialog)

Comment: @cigien well, that mostly focused on the click not closing the dialog, but yep, pretty much.

Comment: [Ahha](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=8587460#8587460) Ollie!