# An edit to a post wiped out the moderator flag I was typing for it

Tags: bug, edits, flags, user-interface, flag-dialog

Here's what happened:

- I opened the flag dialog, selected "in need of moderator intervention" and typed some stuff, spending some time, cross referencing some other pages
- Someone else edited the post, causing the "click to reload" thing on the top of the post (off screen)
- I clicked inside the text box in the flag dialog and suddenly what I had spent some time typing was gone, with little evidence as to why. (The flag dialog was open, back as if I had just clicked on it.) A less experienced user has no chance of understanding what happened, and may think that flagging just isn't possible.

I certainly wasn't flagging to say that everything was fine, so this was especially frustrating. On the flip side, especially as a moderator, I hope this doesn't prevent people for whatever reason from flagging what needs to be flagged.

You can reproduce this yourself by opening two tabs for the same post in the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/323179).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save custom flag content if dialog is dismissed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366410/save-custom-flag-content-if-dialog-is-dismissed)

Comment: @Ollie Saving the text would prevent it from being wiped out, but that's only one part of the problem. The flag dialog should not do anything when I click inside it because that's confusing and frustrating. (In fact, I may have refreshed the page in reaction to it happening, in which case persisting the message to JS storage wouldn't have helped.)

Comment: I actually can't reproduce this, oddly.  Done step-by-step in the Sandbox.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saying that persisting the message to `localStorage` wouldn't have helped, given that your refreshed the page. Values stored in `localStorage` are persisted across page reloads.

Comment: I agree this information shouldn't be lost and that SE should make changes such that it isn't.However, it is, unfortunately, very common for such data to be lost on *many*, perhaps even most, websites under various circumstances . Personally, I use a browser extension, [Textarea Cache](//addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textarea-cache/), which persists text entered into textarea elements in order to prevent loosing this sort of information on all sites (no affiliation, other than long time use; link is to the Firefox extension, but similar extensions exist for Chrome).